# How can I purge stale threads?

Tags: process

I am running a process that serves a web app on Ubuntu 18.04.  After serving the app, it kills the process, but it leaves ghost threads running under the main process, leading to a slow memory leak.  I know this is an issue with the software, but is there anything I can do from the Ubuntu side to clean these stale threads up?  If I run `ps -elfT` I can see all of the ghost threads under the process, but I'm not sure if it's safe to kill them (or even how to kill them).

Here is the portion of `ps -elfT` that is relevant:

```
F S UID        PID  SPID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
1 S ubuntu   32765 32765     1  0  80   0 -  8045 poll_s Jun11 ?        00:00:00 SCREEN voila --template=mytemplate
0 S ubuntu   32766 32766 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 ep_pol Jun11 pts/1   00:02:51 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766   306 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 ep_pol Jun11 pts/1   00:10:50 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766   307 32765  1  80   0 - 367365 ep_pol Jun11 pts/1   02:40:07 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766   308 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun11 pts/1   00:02:12 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766   328 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun11 pts/1   00:02:12 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766   626 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun12 pts/1   00:02:05 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766  2622 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun12 pts/1   00:01:57 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766  2636 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun12 pts/1   00:01:57 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766  2773 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun12 pts/1   00:01:56 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766  2860 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun12 pts/1   00:01:54 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766  3735 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun13 pts/1   00:01:42 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766  3750 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun13 pts/1   00:01:45 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766  3768 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun13 pts/1   00:01:42 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766  4389 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun14 pts/1   00:01:36 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766  6769 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun14 pts/1   00:01:30 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766  7017 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun14 pts/1   00:01:25 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766  9562 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun16 pts/1   00:01:03 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766 11561 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun17 pts/1   00:00:48 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766 11577 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun17 pts/1   00:00:50 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766 12518 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun18 pts/1   00:00:38 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766 12947 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun19 pts/1   00:00:31 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766 12964 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun19 pts/1   00:00:31 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766 13415 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun19 pts/1   00:00:27 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766 13438 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun19 pts/1   00:00:27 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766 13455 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s Jun19 pts/1   00:00:28 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766 22318 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s 06:57 pts/1   00:00:06 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766 23225 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s 16:32 pts/1   00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
1 S ubuntu   32766 23239 32765  0  80   0 - 367365 poll_s 16:32 pts/1   00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/voila --template=mytemplate
```